# Why do *import ...* and *from x import y* idioms behave so differently here?

Tags: python, package

I have a package structure like this:

```
- src
- src/main.py
- src/package1
- src/package1/__init__.py
- src/package1/module1.py
- src/package1/module2.py
```

... where *module2* is a subclass of *module1*, and therefore module1 gets referenced by an absolute import path in *module2.py*.

That is, in *src/package1/module2.py*:

```
from package1.module1 import SomeClassFromModule1
```

**The problem occurs in the *main.py* script:**

```
## here the imports

def main():

        # create an instance of the child class in Module2

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

**Option 1 works. That is, in *src/main.py*:**

```
from package1.module2 import SomeClassFromModule2

some_name = SomeClassFromModule2()
```

**Option 2 does not work. That is, in *src/main.py*:**

```
import package1.module2.SomeClassFromModule2

some_name = package1.module2.SomeClassFromModule2()
```

... causes the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1.module2.SomeClassFromModule2'; 'package1.module2' is not a package
```

**So why is there this difference between the *import* and *from ... import* idiom?**

Would be glad for some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import x` keyword brings all the methods and class from `x` in the the file it is being called.

`from x import y` this brings a specific method or class('y' is a method or class) from that .py file ('x' is the file here) instead of bringing all the methods it has.

In your case when you `import package1.module2` the `SomeClassForModule2()` is being already imported and hence you need not write `import package1.module2.SomeClassFromModule2`

here I guess you want to access a class, so you need to create a object in order to access it.

hope this helped you

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time. I really appreciate that! You solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some test, I think you cannot import a function or class by using `import your_module.your_class`.

It's all about `package, module, function and class`:

```
# import module
>>>import os
<module 'os' from ooxx>

#use module of module (a litte weird)
>>>os.path
<module 'posixpath' from ooxx>

#import module of module (a litte weird)
>>>import os.path

#use function
>>>os.path.dirname
<function posixpath.dirname(p)>

# you cannot import a function (or class) by using 'import your.module.func'
# 'import ooxx' always get a module or package.
>>>import os.path.dirname
ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'os.path.dirname'; 'os.path' is not a package                  

# instead of it, using 'from your_module import your_function_or_class'
>>>from os.path import dirname
<function posixpath.dirname(p)>
```